# What is the MathJax code for an index notation (n over k)

Tags: mathjax

What is the MathJax code required to properly format an index notation for Pascal's Pyramid like so: [N over K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQU3W.png)

[The cheatsheet here at MetaStackoverflow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) has not yielded me results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple matrix.

```
\begin{pmatrix}
   n \\
   k
\end{pmatrix}
```

This will generate the wanted result.

Comment: And matricesare mentioned in the link you shared. It is part of the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Confirmed that this works; i wasn't aware the index notation was categorized under 'matrices'!